# What is the ideal wireless protocol that is best suited for wireless nerve impulse transmission?

Tags: circuit-analysis, wireless, signal-integrity, conversion, medical

I am working to develop a way to transmit nerve impulses wirelessly (or wired) past a break in the spinal cord. What would be the ideal protocol to effectively relay the signal? Even if the device was limited it could be used for select paths like the bladder nerve for instance.

I have concerns with possible interruption or interference. Is frequency coalescence an issue? Perhaps the impulses simply need to be read, have the frequency information transmitted and then recreated rather than transmitting the actual signal itself?